# How to import `json` package in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using python3.6. Below code is to use json module to parse data:

```
import urllib.request
from pandas import *
from pandas import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib
import time
def request_image_info(lat, lon):
    res = urllib.request.urlopen('https://biocache.ala.org.au/ws/explore/group/Plants.json?lat='+str(lat)+'&lon='+str(lon)+'&pageSize=1&radius=1')
    json_data = json.load(res)
    guid = json_data[0]['guid']
    name = json_data[0]['name']
    family = json_data[0]['family']
    common_name = json_data[0]['commonName']
    count = json_data[0]['count']
    rank = json_data[0]['rank']
    kingdom = json_data[0]['kingdom']
    image_id = time.time()
```

I got below error when run this code. The line19 is the code `json_data = json.load(res)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loadImages.py", line 57, in <module>
    request_image_info(row[2], row[3])
  File "loadImages.py", line 19, in request_image_info
    json_data = json.load(res)
  File "/Users/admin/tmp/p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_depr_module.py", line 61, in __getattr__
    obj = getattr(deprmodule, name)
AttributeError: module 'pandas.json' has no attribute 'load'
```

I have installed pandas module as below:

```
$ pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)
```

how can I solve this issue?

Below is the python and pip version I am using:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.2
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Users/admin/tmp/p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Comment: `json` is a standard python module. You don't need to install it from anywhere.  The error you're getting is for `pandas.json`.

Comment: If you make a file with *only* those four lines of code, does it give you the same error?

Comment: This url is taking HTTP 500, anyway.

Comment: @larsks How to solve `pandas.json` issue? I tried to install `pip install pandas.json` but it didn't find the module.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I didn't put the entire url so the url misses some parameters

Comment: Just try `pip install pandas`. And instead import json, use `form pandas import json`.

Comment: I have removed `import json` and put `from pandas import json` but still got the same error.

Comment: I can reproduce this error by importing json first and then `from pandas import json`. Are you really sure that with only those four lines you get the same error? Try to `import json as test_json` and `test_json.load(res)`, maybe it will help to localize the problem

Comment: `pandas.json` really doesn't have function `load`. But I don't beleive the error is from the code you show. Please show us the code. Or show an error from that code.

Comment: @phd Thanks for pointing out this. I have updated my answer to include all source code.

Comment: Why are you importing `pandas.json` at all instead of the regular `json` module? I don't think `pandas.json` is what you actually need here.

Comment: @user2357112 I think you are right, I should import `json` instead of `pandas.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing wrong `json`. Remove

```
from pandas import json
```

and do

```
import json
```

instead.